# Transfer column of dates into cumulative counts for each zipcode

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My dataframe contains houses (id's) located in zipcodes, that purchased a product on a certain date. I would like to add a column to my dataframe that, for every ID, adds up the number of purchases in the zipcode up untill that point, minus 3 months. So for a row that contains a purchase on December 30th, I would add up all the purchases in that zip code up until September 30th.

I already converted the purchase date column to a datetime format.

My dataset looks like this below. As you can see, between row 2 and 3, there is a period of almost 2 years where nothing happened in that area.

```
Id:    Zipcode:   Purchase_Date:
1        9999      2017-August-24
2        9999      2017-December-30
3        9999      2019-July-14
4        2000      2017-March-11
5        2000      2018-May-14
etc.
```

Ideally, the end result would look like this:

```
Id:    Zipcode:   Purchase_Date:      Cumulative_purchases:
1        9999      2017-August-24        0
2        9999      2017-December-30      1       
3        9999      2019-July-14          1
4        2000      2017-March-11         0
5        2000      2017-May-14           0           
etc.
```